# How to use Composer for Kohana

Tags: php, composer-php, kohana-3

I have a website built on the Kohana framework. I see now that there exists Composer packages on [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=kohana) for the various components like `core` and the standard modules like `auth` and `database`.

What steps should I take to make my existing website "Composerized"?

I have lightly used Composer in other projects, but unsure what I should do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply install composer

http://getcomposer.org/

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Run a `composer init` to set up a new composer file. Then go and find your package you wish to install, so for example mine looks something like this

```
{
"require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.24",
    "phing/phing": "dev-master",
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "dev-master",
    "modulargaming/kostache": "dev-master",
    "codeception/codeception": "dev-master",
    "erusev/parsedown": "dev-master",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.3.*"
    }
}
```

Then just run `composer install` or `composer update`

You can then just comment out the modules in `bootstrap.php`

That is a very simple composer.json file, but gives you a basic idea.

Comment: One wouldn't usually require PHPUnit and Phing as regular packages, but as development packages under the "require-dev" key. Also, the usage of "dev-master" should be avoided unless there is a known good reason to - Composer works so much better for everyone if people would stick to using tagged versions and semantic versioning.

Comment: And where/how does the Kohana dependencies come in here?

Comment: You would need to find what Kohana needs from packagist and add them to your composer. https://packagist.org/search/?q=kohana A good place to start.